# Where's the Python 2.6.6 Mac OS X Installer Disk Image?

Tags: python, installation, python-2.6

[Python 2.6.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/) was released on August 24, 2010. However, there isn't a Mac OS X Installer Disk Image. Is there a Mac OS X Installer Disk Image available for Python 2.6.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer can now be downloaded at http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/

Answer (score 1):

[ORIGINAL: Unfortunately, the official python.org OS X installer for 2.6.6 is not yet available.  I expect it should be available soon.]

UPDATE: As of 2010-08-31, it is available [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/).

The installer image you mention in your own answer is one produced by a daily testing buildbot, not by the python.org core developer for OS X, so it should not be considered the official installer.

Answer (score 0):

After a little searching, I did find `python-2.6.6-macosx10.3-2010-08-24.dmg` available from the [daily-dmg Python page](http://www.python.org/dev/daily-dmg/).

**Update:** As Ned Deily states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604669/wheres-the-python-2-6-6-mac-os-x-installer-disk-image/3605033#3605033), the daily-dmg listed above is *not* the official Python.org Mac OS X Installer Disk Image.